# Leap Motion library for processing that works on webpage

Tags: javascript, web, processing, leap-motion

I had a question about processing, JavaScript, and leap motion. I wrote a sketch in processing which I want to run on a webpage. I used this to load the sketch on my webpage:

```
canvas data-processing-sources="helloweb/helloweb.pde">"</canvas>
```

The problem is that I used the `leapmotionP5` library to initialize my leap motion. My question is now: is there any library that works when you load your sketch and load it in HTML like you do with the `processing.js` and the `minim.js`, for example? I need to do this because I need my school project to be written in processing but displayed on a webpage.

Comment: This would probably be a good question to ask your classmates or teacher's aide, but asking for library recommendations is actually "off-topic" on Stack Overflow. If you run into any problems implementing a particular library, though, please feel free to ask about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking whether there's a JavaScript library for Leap Motion, then like I said in your other question, the answer is yes.

A quick google search of "[leap motion javascript](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=leap%20motion%20javascript)" returns a bunch of results, including [an official JavaScript API for Leap Motion](https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/javascript/index.html).

That API page links to many tutorial and examples, including pages for [setting up a project](https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/javascript/devguide/Project_Setup.html) and an example [Hello World](https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/javascript/devguide/Sample_Tutorial.html) program.

That API is named **LeapJS**, and another [google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=leapjs) returns even more results.

All of that being said, converting your sketch from Processing/Java to JavaScript might be a bit challenging for a novice, especially since you said your project is due on Wednesday. Are you sure your project needs to be embedded in a webpage? You might consider just linking to a `.jar` file instead. That way you can continue using your Java libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Kevin, but my question was a bit strange. I just needed all my processing code to work in a htmlpage. But I talked to my lector about it and he says there is no way I could get all the processing libraries to work on a browser. I'm sorry for this. And thank you !

Comment: @DarthSwedo No problem. If any of the answers you've received so far have helped you, you might consider upvoting and accepting them. Happy coding!